# Typescript 1.8 to 2.5 error Type IPromise<{}>' is not assignable to type 'IPromise<IWebErrors[]>

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this? i saw I am supposed to add .topromise() or use a then, but that is not working.

```
getWebErrors(): ng.IPromise<Array<IWebErrors>> {

        var defer = this.q.defer();

        this.http({
            url: `/api/v1/admin/GetWebErrors`,
            method: "GET"
        })
            .success((response: IQuote) => {
                defer.resolve(response);
            })
            .catch(reason => {
                defer.reject();
            });

        return defer.promise;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type checking has gotten stricter in newer versions of TS. In this case the reason is that if you don't specify the type parameter for `defer` the default will be `{}`. The simple solution is to specify the type parameter for `defer`, also for `http`

```
// Assumed missing types
interface IQuote extends Array<IWebErrors> {}
interface IWebErrors {}

getWebErrors(): ng.IPromise<Array<IWebErrors>> {
    var defer = this.q.defer<Array<IWebErrors>>();

    this.http<IQuote>({
        url: `/api/v1/admin/GetWebErrors`,
        method: "GET"
    })
    .success((response) => {
        defer.resolve(response);
    })
    .catch(reason => {
        defer.reject();
    });

    return defer.promise;
}
```